# Is there an application to log component temperatures to file?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I purchased a computer a month or two ago (core i7,  24gb ram, geforce gtx 590, windows 7 ultimate).  Within the last week it began to bluescreen regularly.  I tried lots of things (check hds, check memory, reinstall windows etc..) but it still bluescreened.   At the time my temps were as follows...

CPU - aprox 40/50c.
GPU - arpox 60 idle,  aprox 90 during heavy use.
HDDs  - aprox 55c after the PC had been on a while.

I thought the 55c was ok,  but I have since realized it was probably too high and may have been the direct cause of the bluescreening.

I've installed a spare fan I had in the front of the PC blowing air in, (so there's airflow from front to back)

Since then, obviously, all my temps are down.  Especially the HDDs - three of them reach 30c and one has been up to 47c (it is some distance away from the airflow, in one of the 5.25inch drive bays)

I haven't had the PC on for as long as it would normally take to bluescreen yet,  but If it does I want to know what all the temps were right before the bluescreen.  I have tried Everest but it only shows me realtime temps or gives me the ability to create one-off reports.

I want something that can record all the temps to a file at 30 seconds intervals.  If the computer bluescreens I can load it up again and check the last entry in the file.

**Side question:**  Am I right in thinking 55c was far too hot for a HDD?  (It might have got higher than that before the bluescreens.. I don't know)

**Another side question:**  Is 47c too high?  This is actually why I am asking the main question - I am concerned that this one drive that isn't getting the benefit of the extra fan may still cause the computer to bluescreen.

Comment: For hard drives, 47 °C should be safe, but 55 °C is a bit on the high side. It shouldn't cause any immediate problems like BSODs, though.

Comment: But they may have been getting higher than that, just before the bsods.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I use [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) for monitoring temperatures on my computers. It can be configured to log temperatures to a file:

1. in the main window, click **Configure**
2. go to the **Log** tab and check the **Enabled** checkbox
3. go to the **Temperatures** tab, click on each temperature you want to log and check the **Logged** checkbox at the bottom
4. click **OK**
5. log files will be located in the directory you installed SpeedFan to

Answer (score 27):

I can recommend http://openhardwaremonitor.org/   The application is under active development and is based on .net, doesn't require installation and logs to CSV.

Light on resources and even has a graphing as well as the ability to serve a webpage so you may monitor remotely. To boot, its open source so you have options if you are not happy with it.

Comment: The CVS log file is located in the same directory as the executable. You can additionally set a logging interval.

Answer (score 5):

Another couple of programs, for the CPU and Graphics card respectively are [Coretemp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) and [GPU-z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/), both of which can be set to log to a file.

They are rather more single-purpose than Speedfan or others, but GPU-z can show you quite a bit more about your graphics card such as memory usage, load and fan speed.