# Computer crashes when playing games

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash

There may be a question like this, but my situation is different.

I am on an:
HP Pavilion dv3
Windows 7 32 bit
3 GB RAM
286GB Hard Drive
Intel Core 2 Duo P8700 2.53 ghz 
Nvidia Geforce G 105M

The computer is unmodded and stock.

The computer seems to crash after a few minutes of playing games like Minecraft or World of Tanks. When it blacks out and crashes it makes a 0.1 second long whining sound high pitched.

Also, during normal usage (no games) (im doing web browsing) the fan runs hot and pretty high pitched too.

Comment: how about temperature?

Comment: feeling it is pretty hot. @brobken but not enough to burn you.

Comment: maybe you can try to log temp and system usage?

Comment: here you can find some log programs -> http://superuser.com/questions/412763/is-there-an-application-to-log-component-temperatures-to-file

Comment: I am completely new to this program. what parts of it should i report back to you? @brobken

Comment: here see if this helps. http://prntscr.com/5ukx1j

Comment: Here is another one when the fan runs louder than the first screenie. http://prntscr.com/5uky35

Comment: if these are temps when you're not gaming, these or too high... if you start playing games at these temps it logical that you're crashing, cpu max temp of your pavillion is arround 100°c and gpu is looking too hot too...

Comment: should i buy a fan to cool it down?

Comment: here's a photo if i wake it up from sleep http://prntscr.com/5umlgh

Comment: and the graph. the tallest part is when i held down ctrl+t. the only program open is chrome http://prntscr.com/5ummfd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20371/discussion-between-brobken-and-player72).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your laptop is getting too high in temperature.

It is good that you enable logging, within for ex Speedfan configure tab.
When you enable it, it gives you an idea of how much you are asking from your computer components.

What you can actually do is, following:

- Get your laptop in pieces
- Replace all thermal paste/grease with high quality (like for ex Arctic Silver)
- Remove dust from fans/radiators and/or replace them with higher air flow fans
- (laptop cooling pad can also make some improvement)

If you're not familiar with this, get help from an expert!

Also keep in mind that maybe your system in idle is already overloaded with tasks and processes. So keep track of this too... maybe you can tighten up your system. for exemple only when playing games.

Hope this advice will make a difference.

Comment: no problem, enjoy gaming!

Comment: haha, lol ok :P

Comment: Also check the power supply. Has it got enough oomph to satisfy the hardware. (Say, at least 550W.)

Comment: reopened. check my comment on the question

Comment: @SadBunny where do i find that? on the power cord? it says 65 W

Comment: Normally on the power supply unit (PSU) inside the computer case. But I now read that you say "computer is unmodded and stock", which probably rules out a weak PSU because HP designed the machine this way, i.e. probably wouldn't have put a PSU in it that can't handle the load. This generally only starts to be a possible problem when you start adding lots of hardware, like multiple harddisks, heavier CPU, power-hungry graphics card etc.. So for now, forget this as a possible problem. Also, now that I google your computer model name, it turns out to be a laptop :) So... Never mind my suggestion.

Comment: woopsies. lol thanks for answering though @SadBunny